# Кликер, количество очков за клик

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

День добрый, надо что-бы, после получения 15 очков,после нажатия на зеленую кнопку, при нажатии на красную, давалось 2 очка за одно нажатие, после покупки давалось 4 очка за одно нажатие, 6 за нажатие и т.д. не могу разобраться, помогите пожалуйста, буду благодарен (да, я не умею формулировать вопросы), вот ссылка: https://codepen.io/redbelkared/pen/XWJxxYZ

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Кликер</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Cristall normal";
            src: url("17253.ttf");
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
        }
        button {
            cursor: pointer;
            width: 280px;
            height: 280px;
            font-size: 25px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            background-color: #f54545;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
            border: 30px double #e02424;
            outline: none;
        }
        button:active {
            background-color: #cf3434;
            border: 30px double #ab1515;
        }
        input {
            text-align: center;
            border: none;
            padding: 18px;
            width: 90%;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            font-size: 100px;
            font-family: "Cristall normal";
            margin-top: 0px;
            border-radius: 50px;
        }
        .you {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
        }
        .autoclicker {
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
        .buttonclicker {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        .kup:hover {
            background-color: #bee8fa;
        }
        .upgrade:hover {
            background-color: #a0e8a0;
        }
        .click {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .upgrade {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .kup {
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .upgrader {
            font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function update() {
            document.getElementById('text').value = cookiecount;
            document.title = cookiecount + " Коинов";
            document.getElementById('ammountAutoClick').innerHTML = "Ты имеешь " + autoClick + " Автокликеров";
            document.getElementById('costAutoClick').innerHTML = ((autoClick+1) * 12) + " Коинов";
        }

        var cookiecount = 0;
        var uupgrade = 0;
        var autoClick = 0;
        var delta = 1;

        function add() {
            cookiecount = cookiecount + delta;
            document.getElementById('text').value = cookiecount;
            document.title = cookiecount + " Коинов";
        }

        function timer() {
            cookiecount = cookiecount + autoClick;
            update()
        }
        setInterval(timer, 1000)
    </script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function nocopy(event) { 
                var event = event || window.event; 
                if (event.preventDefault) { event.preventDefault(); } 
                else { event.returnValue = false; } 
                return false; 
            } 

            document.onmouseup = nocopy; 
            document.onmousemove = nocopy; 
            document.ondragstart = nocopy; 
            document.onselectstart = nocopy; 
            document.ontextmenu = nocopy; 
            document.oncopy = nocopy;
    </script>
<body style="text-align: center;margin-top: 80px;margin-right: 0;margin-left: 0;">
    <a class="click" onclick="add()"><button><h1>Нажми</h1></button></a>
    <br><br>
    <div class="coins">
    <p class="you">У тебя:<p>
    <input type="text" id="text" value="0" disabled="0">
    </div>
    <div class="box1" style="display: inline-block;margin-top: 40px;padding-right: 45px;">
        <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 20px;">Автокликер:</p>
                <div class="buttonclicker" style="background-color: #d9f0fa;padding-top: 15px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;display: inline-block;border-radius: 9px;">
                <a class="kup" style="text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-family: sans-serif;color: #0a0a0a;font-size: 20px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;border-radius: 9px;" onclick="buyAutoClick()">  Купить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="autoclicker">
                <p id="costAutoClick"> Коинов</p>
                <p id="ammountAutoClick">Ты имеешь 0 Автокликеров</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box2" style="display: inline-block;margin-top: 40px;padding-left: 45px;">
        <p style="font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 20px;">Прокачать клик:</p>
                <div class="upgradee" style="background-color: #bdf2bd;padding-top: 15px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-left: 0px;margin-left: 0px;margin-right: 0px;display: inline-block;border-radius: 9px;">
                <a class="upgrade" onclick="buyUpgrade()" style="text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-family: sans-serif;color: #0a0a0a;font-size: 20px;padding-top: 15px;padding-bottom: 15px;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;border-radius: 9px;">Купить</a>
                </div>
                <div class="upgrader">
                <p id="costUpgrade">Цена: 15 Коинов</p>
                <p id="ammountUpgrade"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function buyAutoClick() {
            if (cookiecount >= ((autoClick+1) * 12)) {
                cookiecount = cookiecount - ((autoClick+1) * 12);
                autoClick = autoClick + 1;
                update()
            }
        }
        function buyUpgrade() {
             if (cookiecount >= ((uupgrade+1) * 15)) {
                cookiecount = cookiecount - ((uupgrade+1) * 15);
                uupgarde = uupgrade + 1;
                update()
            }

            delta = 2;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В самом конце ф-ции `buyUpgrade` написано `delta = 2`. Измените на:

```
  if(delta == 1){
    delta = 2;
  } else{
    delta += 2;
  }
```

Comment: Cпасибо большое! :)